# in bash shell: extract part of the output of a command and output to file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, mount

Say I run "mount" on Bash, I get something like this:

```
--]$mount
/dev/disk1 on / (journaled)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
//user@server/share on ***/user/share*** (afpfs, mounted ***by user***)
```

From lines where "mounted by user" = 'someUser' I would like to output to file the part with the path to the local mount point "/user/share".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a line that matches "mounted by", print column 3:

```
mount | awk '/mounted by / { print $3 }'
```

Comment: I did go around this awk command a few times and couldn't make it work :)  Thanks for the help!